# Asteroids Canvas Game: Splitting the asteroid

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm still making Asteroids game in canvas in html5. Everything were going good, but now I'm in deadlock. Collision works, but I have no idea how to split an asteroid after shooting in it.

Here is code:

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown',doKeyDown,true);
window.addEventListener('keyup',doKeyUp,true);
var canvas = document.querySelector('#pageCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var angle = 0;
var H = /*500;*/window.innerHeight; //*0.75,
var W = /*500;*/window.innerWidth; //*0.75;
canvas.width = W;
canvas.height = H;
var xc = W/2; //zeby bylo w centrum :v
var yc = H/2; //jw.
var x =  xc;
var y =  yc;
var dv = 0.2;
var dt = 1;
var vx = 0;
var vy = 0;
var fps = 30;
var maxVel = 5;
var maxVelLeft = -5;
var frict = 0.99;
var brakes = 0.90;
var keys = new Array();
var fire = false;
var points = 0;
var lives = 3;
var randomize = true;
//zamiennik do setintervala
var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || 
     window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
     window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
     window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
var fps = 30;
var now;
var then = Date.now();
var interval = 1000/fps;
var delat;


//laser
var laserF = false;
var lasery = [];
var shootVel = 12;  //velocity of laser

//asteroids
var asteroidy = [];



 var newasteroid1 ={
   ax : ((Math.round(Math.random()*1000))%500),
   ay : ((Math.round(Math.random()*1000))%500),
   avx : 1*(Math.random() > 0.5 ? -1 : 1),
   avy : 1*(Math.random() > 0.5 ? -1 : 1),
   ar : 30,
   aangle : 3,
   colour : "gray"
  };
  asteroidy.push(newasteroid1);

 var newasteroid2 ={
   ax : ((Math.round(Math.random()*1000))%500),
   ay : ((Math.round(Math.random()*1000))%500),
   avx : 1*(Math.random() > 0.5 ? -1 : 1),
   avy : 1*(Math.random() > 0.5 ? -1 : 1),
   ar : 30,
   aangle : 2,
   colour : "gray"
  };
  asteroidy.push(newasteroid2);    
  
 var newasteroid3 ={
   ax : ((Math.round(Math.random()*1000))%500),
   ay : ((Math.round(Math.random()*1000))%500),
   avx : 1*(Math.random() > 0.5 ? -1 : 1),
   avy : 1*(Math.random() > 0.5 ? -1 : 1),
   ar : 30,
   aangle : 2,
   colour : "gray"
  };
  asteroidy.push(newasteroid3);
  
 var newasteroid4 ={
   ax : ((Math.round(Math.random()*1000))%500),
   ay : ((Math.round(Math.random()*1000))%500),
   avx : 1*(Math.random() > 0.5 ? -1 : 1),
   avy : 1*(Math.random() > 0.5 ? -1 : 1),
   ar : 30,
   aangle : 0,
   colour : "fuchsia"
  };
  asteroidy.push(newasteroid4);
 



function doKeyUp(evt){
 keys[evt.keyCode] = false;
 fire = false;
 if (laserF) {
  var newlaser ={
   lx: x,
   ly: y, 
   //lw : 4,
   //lh : 4,
   lr : 2,
   lvx : Math.cos(convertToRadians(angle)),
   lvy : Math.sin(convertToRadians(angle))
   }
  lasery.push(newlaser);
  laserF = false;
 }
 
}

function doKeyDown(evt){
 keys[evt.keyCode] = true;
 
 if(40 in keys && keys[40]){
  if(randomize){
  x = (Math.round(Math.random()*1000))%W;
  y = (Math.round(Math.random()*1000))%H;
  vx = 0;
  vy = 0;
  randomize = false;
  setTimeout(function(){randomize = true;}, 2000);
  }
 }
 
 

}

function drawPoints(){
  context.save();
  context.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillText("Score: " + points, 50, 50);
  context.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
  context.fill();
  context.closePath();
  context.restore();
 }
 
function drawLives(){
  context.save();
  context.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillText(lives + " lives left", 150, 50);
  context.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
  context.fill();
  context.closePath();
  context.restore();
 }

function drawAsteroids(idx){
 var asteroid = asteroidy[idx];
 context.save();
 context.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
 context.rotate(0);
 context.translate(asteroid.ax, asteroid.ay);
 context.rotate(asteroid.aangle);
 context.translate(-25,-25);
 context.beginPath();
 context.fillText(asteroid.ax + " " + asteroid.ay, 0,50);
 context.arc(0, 0, asteroid.ar, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
 context.fillStyle = asteroid.colour;
 context.fill();
 context.closePath();
 /*beginPath();
 moveTo(0,0);
 lineTo()*/
 context.restore();
}

function moveAsteroids(idx){
 var asteroid = asteroidy[idx]
 asteroid.ax += asteroid.avx;
 asteroid.ay += asteroid.avy;
 asteroid.aangle += 0.009;
 if(asteroid.ax > W){
  asteroid.ax = 0 -25;
  } 
 else{
  if(asteroid.ax < -25){
   asteroid.ax = W;
  }
 }
 
 if(asteroid.ay > H){
  asteroid.ay = 0 -25;
 }
 else{
  if(asteroid.ay < -25){
   asteroid.ay = H;
  }
 }
}

function drawLaser(idx) {
 var laser = lasery[idx];
 context.save();
 context.translate(laser.lx,laser.ly);  
 context.fillStyle = "red";
 //context.fillText(laser.lx + " " + laser.ly,10,10);
 //context.fillRect(0,0,laser.lw,laser.lh);
 context.beginPath();
 context.arc(0, 0, laser.lr, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
 context.fillStyle = "red";
 context.fill();
 context.closePath();
 
 context.restore();
}

function moveLaser(idx) {
 var laser = lasery[idx];
 laser.lx += laser.lvx * shootVel;
 laser.ly += laser.lvy * shootVel;
 if (laser.lx > W || laser.lx < 0 || laser.ly > H || laser.ly < 0) {
  lasery.splice(idx, 1);
 }
}



//OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
function ogienZdupy(){
  context.fillStyle = "red";
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(-2,2);
  context.lineTo(2,10);
  context.lineTo(-2,18);
  context.lineTo(-25,10);
  context.lineTo(-2,2);
  context.strokeStyle = "red";
  context.stroke();
 }

function convertToRadians(degree) {
 return degree*(Math.PI/180);
}

function incrementAngle() {
 angle += 5;
 if(angle > 360){
  angle = 0;
  }
}

function decrementAngle(){
 angle -= 5;
 if(angle > 360){
  angle = 0;
  }
}
function xyVelocity(){
 vx += dv * Math.cos(convertToRadians(angle)); //* friction;
 vy += dv * Math.sin(convertToRadians(angle)); //* friction;
 if(vx > maxVel){
  vx = maxVel;
 }
 if(vy < maxVelLeft){
  vy = maxVelLeft;
 }
 
 if(vx < maxVelLeft){
  vx = maxVelLeft;
 }
 
 if(vy > maxVel){
  vy = maxVel;
 }
 
}

function shipMovement(){
 
 
 if(66 in keys && keys[66]){ //it's B
  vx = 0;
  vy = 0;
 }
 
 if(38 in keys && keys[38]){
  xyVelocity();
  fire = true;
 }
 
 if(37 in keys && keys[37]){
  decrementAngle();
 };
 if (39 in keys && keys[39]){
  incrementAngle();
 };
 if (32 in keys && keys[32]){
  laserF = true;
 };
 
}

function xyAndFriction(){
 
 x += vx * dt;
 y += vy * dt;
 
 vx *= frict;
 vy *= frict;
 
}

function outOfBorders(){
 
 if(x > W){
  x = x - W;
  }
 if(x< 0){
  x = W;
 }
 
 if(y > H){
  y = y - H;
 }
 
 if(y < 0){
  y = H;
 }
}

function blazeatron420(){  //the ship
 context.beginPath();
 context.moveTo(0,0);
 context.lineTo(20,10);
 context.lineTo(0,20);
 context.lineTo(7,10);
 context.lineTo(0,0);
 context.strokeStyle = "green";
 context.stroke();
}

function space(){
 context.fillStyle = "black";
 context.fillRect(0,0,W,H);
}
/*
function superLaserCollider(){
 for(var i in asteroidy){
  var ax = asteroidy[i].ax,
   ay = asteroidy[i].ay,
   ar = asteroidy[i].ar
   
  
 
 
  for(var j in lasery){
   var xl = lasery[j].lx,
    yl = lasery[j].ly,
    rl = lasery[j].lr
    }
    
    }
 /*var dx = Math.abs(ax - (xl+wl/2));
 var dy = Math.abs(ay - (yl+yl/2));
 
 if(dx > ar + wl){
  return (false);
 }
 if(dy > ar + hl){
  return (false);
 }
 if(dx <= wl){
  return (true);
 }
 if(dy <= hl){
  return (true);
 }
 var dx = dx - wl;
 var dy = dy - hl;
 return(dx * dx + dy * dy <= ar * ar);
 
 
 var dx = ax - xl;
 var dy = ay - yl;
 var distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy); 
 if(xl > ax && yl > ax){
  console.log("kolizja");
 }
 
 
}
*/
function bigAsteroidExplosion(idx){
 var asteroid = asteroidy[idx];
 context.clearRect(asteroid.ax, asteroid.ay, 100, 100);

}

function superLaserCollider(){
  for(var i in asteroidy){
   var ax = asteroidy[i].ax,
    ay = asteroidy[i].ay,
    ar = asteroidy[i].ar;
    
   for(var j in lasery){
    var xl = lasery[j].lx,
     yl = lasery[j].ly,
     rl = lasery[j].lr;
    
    var dx = ax - xl;
    var dy = ay - yl;
    var distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy); 
    if(distance < ar + rl){
     console.log("kabom");
     points = points + 100;
     //alert("BOOM");
     console.log(points);
    }
   }
  }
 }
  

 /*
     context.beginPath();
     context.fillText(points, 100, 100);
     context.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
     context.fill();
     context.closePath();
 */
function drawEverything() {  
 shipMovement();
 xyAndFriction();
 outOfBorders();

 //context.save();
 //;
 
 space();
 context.save();
 context.translate(x,y);
 //context.translate(25,25);
 context.rotate(convertToRadians(angle));
 context.translate(-7,-10);
 
 if(fire){
  ogienZdupy();
 }
 
     
 context.fillStyle = "green";
 //context.fillText(vx + " ｋｍ／ｈ",50,50);
 /*context.fillText("dupa",-30,0);
 context.beginPath();
 context.moveTo(-20,5);
 context.lineTo(-5,10);
 context.strokeStyle = "green"; //KOLOR LINII ;_;
 context.stroke();*/
 
 if(asteroidy.length > 0 ){
 for (var tmp in asteroidy){
  drawAsteroids(tmp);
  moveAsteroids(tmp);
  
  }
 }
 //putAsteroids();
 blazeatron420();
 //shootAsteroid(idx);
 context.translate(-x+7,-y+10);
 drawPoints();    
 drawLives();
 context.restore();
 console.log(asteroidy.length);
 
 //superCollider();
 //for(var i = 0; i < asteroidy.length; i++)

 if(lasery.length > 0){

  for (var tmp in lasery) {
   
   drawLaser(tmp);
   moveLaser(tmp);
  }   
  
  
 }
     
 
 superLaserCollider();
 
 
 
}
 

//setInterval(drawEverything, 20);
function draw(){
 requestAnimationFrame(draw);
 now = Date.now();
 delta = now - then;
 if (delta > interval){
  then = now - (delta % interval);
 }
 
 drawEverything();
}

draw();
```

```css
body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<body>
<canvas id="pageCanvas" style="display:block">
You do not have a canvas enabled browser. Please, stop using IE :P
</canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "you have no idea"? Don't you know how to remove one? Don't you know how to add two new ones? Don't you know how to calculate the size of the new ones? Don't you know how to calculate the trajectories of the two new ones? Please specify.

Comment: When you made up your mind, please also edit the title for your question so it describes your actual question. A "[Deadlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock)" is a very specific problem in programming and your question has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I know how to add two new ones by taking pattern from adding each of the bigger ones, but the problem is how to remove that bigger ones :/

Comment: Did you read [the documentation about arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)?